# format issue when saving captured data with request.POST

Tags: python, django

The data is being captured, however when saving to the database it is being saved with quotes and square brackets.

```
def create_flow_and_phases(request):


    data = {
        "name": request.POST['new_flow_name'],
        "description": request.POST['flow_description'],
        "category": request.POST['select_category'],
        "precedents": [request.POST['precedent_list']],
        "users": [1],
        "phases": ''
    }

    # Making a POST request to save flow_and_phases
    url = API_HOST + "/api/flows/save_flow_and_phases/"

    answer = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + request.session['user_token']})

    if not answer.ok:
        raise Exception("An error occurred while creating flow.")
```

Example of data in DB: Name: ['test']

I'm using Django Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to pass the data dictionary as a JSON and it worked

```
answer = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + request.session['user_token']})
```